# Create programatically UITableViewController with user defined cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created `UITableViewController` programatically in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
resultsController = UITableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
resultsController.tableView.register(MyTableCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userFoundCell")
resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
```

However, when I later do

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   var cell: MyTableCellTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userFoundCell", for: indexPath) as? MyTableCellTableViewCell

   if (cell == nil){
        cell = MyTableCellTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "userFoundCell")
   }

   cell!.lblTmp!.text = "test"
   return cell!
}
```

`cell` is never nil, I have tested it

Code crash with:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   on cell!.lblTmp!.text = "test"

My `MyTableCellTableViewCell` looks like this

```
class MyTableCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lblTmp: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

`IBoutlet` is connected in Interface Builder to GUI elements. The same class is used on another place as well.

Comment: @Sulthan it is connected. Or at least in my second table, that is using the same class, but is inited from IB, all is working

Comment: You said the label is connected but you also said you have no xib file. Since you are not using storyboard either, how exactly are you defining the view for `MyTableCellTableViewCell` and how exactly are you connecting the label?

Comment: @Sulthan I have a storyboard

Comment: You are not using a storyboard though. Your `resultsController` is not instantiated from a storyboard.

Comment: @Sulthan I have combination of both. Something from storyboard, something from code. This is inited from code, on another place from storyboard

Comment: A cell view can be defined in IB in two ways. Either as a separate `xib` that is then registered with a table, or, directly in table view controller in a storyboard. In the second case the cell is limited to that specific controller and it is registered with its table automatically. But only with the table of that specific controller. It is not shared magically to all table view controllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your custom tableview cell with xib and class then you should register your cell by following way.

If you have your table view cell xib file name like "MyTableCellTableViewCell" this then replace your line

```
resultsController.tableView.register(MyTableCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userFoundCell")
```

with this line

```
resultsController.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyTableCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "userFoundCell")
```

Comment: I dont have xib file.

Comment: then how did you make  **@IBOutlet var lblTmp: UILabel!** this line into Custom table view cell.?

Comment: I have it connected to storyboard

Comment: then its a prototype cell.

Comment: `resultsController` would have to be instantiated from that storyboard and from that specific controller which contains the prototype cell.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern of creating cells is wrong:

```
if (cell == nil){
    cell = MyTableCellTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "userFoundCell")
}
```

You should do this instead (force cast using ! is appropriate here in my opinion):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userFoundCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCellTableViewCell
```

If this line crashes, then it means your custom cell was not registered properly. This will help you to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While the cell is not nil, you don't seem to be checking whether or not `lblTmp` is nil.  If `lblTmp` is nil then trying to set `cell!.lblTmp!.text = "test"` will crash with `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.  How are you setting `lblTmp` to a value?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do unwrapping `cell!.lblTmp!.text = "test"`
after declaring an implicitily unwrapped optional     `@IBOutlet var lblTmp: UILabel!`

Use `cell!.lblTmp.text = "test"` instead.